# Lookup subscription in Azure APIM with Primary or Secondary key

Tags: azure, rest, subscription, apim

We're going to use Azure APIM as a gateway in front of our back end APIs. We plan to correlate Azure-managed subscriptions to our users. So we're forwarding the subscription key from the request to our back end and would *like* to look up the subscription using that [primary or secondary] key. However, I don't *think* i see a way using the Azure REST API. Is there such an operation exposed anywhere?

I've looked through the Azure APIM REST docs to no avail.

Comment: You can make use of Get Subscription API here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/subscription/get?tabs=HTTP and filter the properties by properties.primaryKey and properties.secondaryKey

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Which specific endpoint are you referring to? The only one I would think could _possibly_ be used is "List" but that one doesn't include the primary or secondary keys.

Answer (score 0):

***In order to retrieve both the Primary and Secondary Subscription keys for APIM Service you can call the API like below:-***

I have referred this **[MS Document's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/subscription/get?tabs=HTTP)**  Rest API

> **Make sure you append the above document's Rest API with `/listSecrets` and call it as a `POST` request to get the Primary and Secondary Keys like below:-**

**Request:-**

```
POST 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-44d6-b4fd-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/siliconrg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/siliconapim123/subscriptions/xxxxxx8dba6b004f0xxx/listSecrets?api-version=2022-08-01
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: This is useful if you know the subscription id, but what if all you have is the key (primary or secondary) - how can you look up a subscription with only a key (which presumably APIM does)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to cache the result of all "key to subscription" options anyways. So a possible solution would be to first iterate though all APIM subscriptions, then retrieve their primary+secondary keys. Store the results in a way that fits your needs.

Get all APIM subscriptions:

`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/subscriptions?api-version=2022-08-01`

Get all subscription secrets:

`POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/subscriptions/{sid}/listSecrets?api-version=2022-08-01`